# Why This Cycle Doesn't Work If I Done Everything Right

Tags: java

This code give this:

> `Completed with exit code: 0`

But I think here not work cycle; what's wrong?

(I want this expression to give me products A and B C times)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class HelloCodiva {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double a, c, result =0;   
    double d = 0;
    double b = 1.1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = sc.nextInt();
    c = sc.nextDouble();
        
    while ( d<c)
    {
      if (d == c) {
        System.out.println(result);
      }
      else {
        result=a*b;
      d++;};

    }    
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition of while is `d < c`, when d >= c, your program will finish while loop and exit, And never print the result.

In order to get some output print, you can use `while ( d <= c)` ，To avoid infinite loop, remember to `break`;

```
while ( d <= c) { // condition should contains b == c
    if (d == c){
        System.out.println(result);
        break; // should break
    } else {
        result=a*b;
        d++;
    }
}
```